# Javascript form input to csv file

Tags: javascript, json, html, csv, local-storage

I have the following code, see codepen http://codepen.io/Jacqueline34/pen/GZxxRV I think on line 25 my code is the problem but I can see how to correct is (noob alert!).  I can store form input correctly in localstorage but when I open the excel file the file shows [object][object] etc. How can I modify my code to output the localstorage data in the excel file?  This has my head wrecked.  :)

```
$("#save").click(function(e) {                          
    e.preventDefault();                                 
    localStorage.setItem("user_input", "set");          
    var data = $("#contact-form").serializeArray();     
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {                  
            localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);  
        });
        $("#message").html("<p style='color:red'><strong>Thank you.  Your information has been saved</strong></p><br/>"); 
});

    if (localStorage.getItem("user_input") == "set") {          
    var data = $("#contact-form").serializeArray();              
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            $("[name='" + obj.name + "']").val(localStorage.getItem(obj.name));  
        });             
    }

    $(function exportData() {
    var data = $("#contact-form").serializeArray();                         
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
        data += $("[name='" + i + "']") + "," + $("[name='" + obj.name + "']").val();
        }); 
        data += '\r\n';                                                     

        var exportLink = document.createElement('a');                                   
        exportLink.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;base64,' + window.btoa(data));  
        exportLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode('data.csv'));                    
        document.getElementById('results').appendChild(exportLink);                     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your writing down Objects instead of the contents of the Objects.

I've altered your html a little and made a button:

```
<button id="next" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="exportData()">Export</button>
```

I removed the original

```
$(function exportData() { }
```

from your code and placed a new one **outside** the scope of:

```
$(document).ready(function () { }
```

I made the altered export function like this:

```
function exportData() {

    var data = $("#contact-form").serializeArray();
    var out = '';    

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        out += data[i].name + "," + data[i].value;
        out += '\r\n';
    }

    var blob = new Blob([out], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'export.csv');
    } else {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.setAttribute("href", url);
            link.setAttribute("download", 'export.csv');
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        }
    }    
}
```

So this function now stands on itself.
I hope it helps...

Comment: vaultboy - I am over the moon delighted, it now works.  Thank you for your time in answering my question.  Yes I was downloading the Objects but I could not see my way past it.  :)